# Why is JRE 10 outdated and JRE 8 up-to-date?

Tags: java

I (as a non-Java kind of guy) am puzzled that my local JRE 10 installation required an update, but when updating, I get the JRE 8! This is even reported on https://java.com/en/download/more_info10.jsp:

> Users who installed JRE 9 and/or JRE 10 (non Long-Term Support Releases) should remove those out-of-date versions of Java.

I would understand if JRE 11 would be the current version, but no, it's JRE  8:

> If you still require Java on your computer download the latest release of JRE 8 available at java.com, which is the only currently supported major release of Java targeting desktop deployment.

How can this be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The explanation is right there on that page you linked and quoted.

Relevant section highlighted.
"desktop deployment".

> If you still require Java on your computer download the latest release
>   of JRE 8 available at java.com, ***which is the only currently supported
>   major release of Java targeting desktop deployment.***

Short answer:

- Java 9 and 10 are not a [Long Term Support (LTS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long-term_support) release, and have expired.
- Java 8 commercial supports end January 2019, public updates for personal use through December 2020 though.
- Java 11 is the current and is also a LTS support release.

So todays choice is between java 8 and 11. ***But 11 removed applets and browser integration and other desktop technologies*** (JavaFX, java webstart etc). See list below and link to source. See also the Oracle white paper of 2018-03, [*Java Client Roadmap Update*](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/javaclientroadmapupdate2018mar-4414431.pdf).

Further details:
Oracle has decided to stop releasing several variants of JRE on their own. As well as requiring a license for production use for newer releases. For example 32bit variants are no more, traditional desktop variants not available as there is no no java webstart and javafx  is separated out since jdk 11+ etc, Oracle is more focusing on 64bit and server.

Put together with the fact that 9 and 10 are not Long term support releases (and they have expired) this leaves you with the choice of  Java 8 for this particular use case for now.

JDK public updates for java 8 from oracle will end in January 2019 (and December 2020 for personal use) so at least until then is the current desktop java version of choice, from Oracle that is.

The current version of java 11, is only available as a 64bit JDK (development kit download) from oracle. No suitable desktop JRE (just the runtime).

Removed in JDK 11 release from Oracle:
Important Changes and Information
The following are some important changes in and information about this release. In some cases, additional details about the changes described below are provided in these Release Notes.

> - The deployment stack, required for Applets and Web Start Applications, was deprecated in JDK 9 and has been removed in JDK 11.
> - Without a deployment stack, the entire section of supported browsers has been removed from the list of supported configurations of
>     JDK 11.
> - Auto-update, which was available for JRE installations on Windows and macOS, is no longer available.
> - In Windows and macOS, installing the JDK in previous releases optionally installed a JRE. In JDK 11, this is no longer an option.
> - In this release, the JRE or Server JRE is no longer offered. Only the JDK is offered. Users can use jlink to create smaller custom
>     runtimes.
> - JavaFX is no longer included in the JDK. It is now available as a separate download from openjfx.io.

Source: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/11-relnote-issues-5012449.html

Comment: For a moment there you had a lot of "TBD" in your answer.  Your answer should be somewhat complete when you post it.

Comment: Sorry about that, wasn't meant to be published at that time, just my own notes where to fill in further informationw while writing. But those are long gone.

Comment: ...which is why the downvotes happened.  You have plenty of time to write up your answer before you hit the "Submit" button.

Comment: Fully aware of that fact, it was an accident, I've written an answer or two before... The votes would indicate the usefulness of the answer to a reader, to be helpful in that regard: meaning the current version though. Didn't even consider someone had the time to see the initial publication.

Comment: Well, I like the answer (and upvoted). What I basically read is that Oracle messed up the versioning. Very strange that applications relying on special JRE 9 or JRE 10 features are now doomed until JRE 11 is officially released. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Well JRE 11 will probably not happen, not from Oracle anyway. The features removed were generally deprecated in 9 and 10 so shouldn't be any overlap there.

Comment: I just learned that one reason the JRE 11 will probably never happen (although the JDK 11 exists) could be, that from JRE 9 on applications are expected to be self-contained applications. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/self-contained-packaging.html.

Answer (score 4):

Simple:  [Oracle's own support roadmap](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/java-se-support-roadmap.html) lists Java 8 as  having "premier" support until 2022.

Conversely, Java 9 and 10 have had their premier support lapse in March and September of 2018.  Oracle's new update model ensures that non-LTS releases from Java 9 onwards are only officially supported until the new version of Java arrives.

"Current" is a bit of a strong word when it comes to Java; technically, the latest version of Java that should be used by end consumers is Java 11 (as of time of writing), since that is the current LTS.  However, not all applications which *use* Java may be up-to-date, so it's safest to fall back to Java 8 until your application vendor informs you that it's safe to upgrade.

Comment: I fail to see how this answer the question? Generally java releases are highly backwards compatible and releases before Java 8 were fairly quickly updated, and this answer doesn't address this. And "premier" support is not very applicable here?

Comment: @MattiasIsegranBergander:  It does; the main turning point being that Oracle elected to accelerate their own release schedule to every six months, and offer an LTS periodically for those organizations which don't want to keep chasing updates.  Additionally there are some notably backwards-incompatible changes; reflection among other things (e.g. if you use a library which relies on reflection to do some work, you may have some work to do), but also parts of the JDK are being split out and not kept in the default modules, meaning more work to port that across.

Comment: @MattiasIsegranBergander:  If you follow JakartaEE (formerly JavaEE) or JavaFX development, you'll notice that there were some libraries assumed "defacto" in the JDK which now require you to explicitly include them as dependencies.

Comment: _I_ am fully aware of what has changed and what's missing and how to make it work, I'm migrating applications and server software from java 8 to 9, 10 and 11. This answer doesn't even mention these things though, that's my point. :)

Comment: @MattiasIsegranBergander:  Considering that the OP is really asking about the JRE and not *necessarily* the JDK, I think what I have is sufficient.

Comment: Strange I would use the same argument as to say why it's NOT sufficient. As it mentions nothing about JRE and desktops. Then we agree to disagree :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps that's because Java 11 deprecated modules which are present in Java 10 e.g. JAXB or Java FX. Latest Java 8 still has these modules so the software that worked on Java 10 can potentially work with Java 8.